# How to detect multiple keys for a Game Control

Tags: java

I am making a soccer game.My problem is when i am pressing a certain key and a change the key to press my player kind of stops and then responds.like i am going to the left and i press the up button.My problem i think is due to the fact that i dont support multiple keys being pressed once.So i need help on how i can implement this.Here is my code

```
//add keylistener to window frame
    window.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: {

                        window.setVisible(false);
                        TeamMenu.setVisible(true);
                        MainMenu.setVisible(false);
                        g_SoccerPitch.canUpDate = false;


                }
                break;
                case 'r':
                case 'R': {
                    SoccerPitchLock.lock();
                    g_SoccerPitch = null;
                    g_SoccerPitch = new SoccerPitch(cxClient, cyClient);
                    SoccerPitchLock.unlock();
                }
                break;

                case 'p':
                case 'P': {
                    g_SoccerPitch.TogglePause();
                }
                break; 
            }//end switch
        }//end switch        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            if(g_SoccerPitch.GameOn() && g_SoccerPitch != null){

            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {

                case 'w':
                case 'W':{
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveUp();
                    chaseBall();
                }
                break;

                case 's':
                case 'S':{
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveDown();
                   chaseBall();
                }
                break;

                case 'a':
                case 'A':{
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveDown();
                    chaseBall();
                }
                break;

                case 'd':
                case 'D':{
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().MoveRight();
                    chaseBall();
                }
                break;

                case 'm':
                case 'M':{
                     //shoot ball if ball withinin kicking range and team is in control
                     if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.InControl() && g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinKickingRange()){
                      g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().UserPlayerShootBall();
                     }   
                }
                break;

                case 'l':
                case 'L':{
                     //if team in control pass the ball else chase the ball
                     if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.InControl()){

                      if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().BallWithinReceivingRange()){
                      g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().UserPlayerPassBall();
                       }
                        }  else{

                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOn();
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SetTarget(g_SoccerPitch.Ball().m_vPosition);
                    if(g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().AtTarget()){
                    g_SoccerPitch.UserControlledTeam.UserControlledPlayer().Steering().SeekOff();
                    }
                     } 
                }
                break;

            }//end switch
        }//end switch  
        }//closes if           
    });
```

Comment: So you would want to be able to move diagonally I guess? A key press is always a single atomic interface input. Your best bet is to see how you can simultaneously catch two presses and what design you would need!

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple key detection for KeyListener (java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170145/multiple-key-detection-for-keylistener-java)

Answer (score 1):

> You can set boolean variable for all keys. Set value true when key pressed and set false when that key releases. Below is my code in C# for up and left

```
bool isleft = false;
    bool isright = false;
    bool isup = false;
    private void button1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
            isleft = true;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            isup = true;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            if (isleft)
            {
                moveleft();
            }
            moveup();
        }
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
        {
            if (isup)
            {
                moveup();
            }
            moveleft();
        }
    }
    public void moveleft()
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 1, button1.Location.Y);
    }
    public void moveup()
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X , button1.Location.Y-1);
    }

    private void button1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
            isleft = false;
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            isup = false;
    }
```

By this way you can maintain all the moves. I am not good with java syntex so hope this will help

Comment: is the button1_PreviewKeyDown(....) method the same as the the java keyPressed or keyReleased method